# how to simplify font import in css

Tags: css, fonts

I have a font namely SourceSansPro, and I include it in my css as follows:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "SourceSansPro";
    src: url("../font/SourceSansPro-Bold.otf");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "SourceSansPro";
    src: url("../font/SourceSansPro-Regular.otf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "SourceSansPro";
    src: url("../font/SourceSansPro-Light.otf.otf");
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

It's rather redundant. Isn't there a neater way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the @font-face syntax is not very flexible. You're at the mercy of the browser developers in this case. You can, however, segment your fonts into a fonts.css file and just do an import:

```
@import url('css/fonts.css');
```

Another possible solution would be to add the font via [Google's Font API](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace%3ause/Collection%3aSource+Sans+Pro). That way, you don't have to worry about the CSS in the first place. You just add

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro);
```

to your stylesheet. Or you can add

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

to the `<head>` of your document.

Comment: The `@import` declaration is just a way to use the CSS code in different places and does not simplify it. Besides, using the same CSS file for all pages with `<link ...>` may be better. Regarding the use of fonts as hosted by Google, there are several reasons not to do that except in experimentation.

Comment: What reasons? I have used Google's Font API on countless projects without issue. The fonts are loaded asynchronously to avoid delaying your webpage and you are served only the required font format per your browser's requirements (as opposed to @font-face where you must declare all your font formats individually). This, too, trumps the disadvantage of not serving the font locally.

Answer (score 0):

It is not essentially redundant, since you are using three typefaces and they need to be declared separately. You can, however, omit the declarations `font-style: normal` and `font-weight: normal`, since they correspond to defaults.

On the other hand, the code works only on browsers that support OTF as the format of downloadable fonts. Use e.g. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator to generate other formats and code for taking them into use.

The `font-weight: lighter` probably works in most situations, but it is illogical (using relative keyword when you should specify the actual weight) and should be replaced by `font-weight: 200`, which corresponds to the actual weight of the typeface

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the potential problem. Fontsquirrel is really a powerful site for downloading&generating fonts!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're obviously going to need to change the font-family name for each one or I would think that having them all the same would make them clash. At least I would think that. I have never had it happen to me, but if it's not working, then do that. But if not, ignore this.

As for the @font-face simplicity, the only real specifications you need for the @font-face is the font-family and the src. That calls the font style, obviously. So any other web styling you can leave to either the html style or css.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "SourceSansPro";
    src: url("../font/SourceSansPro-Light.otf.otf");
}
```

You can then style your font in either a span or css class.

```
<span style="font-family: SourceSansPro; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">Styled Font</span>
<div style="font-family: SourceSansPro; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">Styled Font</div>
<div class="myspecificstyle">Styled Font</div>
```

If you have a lot of fonts, I would just put them all in one css file and then link it to the page you're using them on.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myfonts.css">
```

Comment: You can keep all the names the same without an issue since the variants are different. You can target each font by just changing the variant.

Comment: My bad. I just haven't done that before. Haven't felt the need since I style my fonts either with html style or css. I prefer to keep it the way I specified for simplicity to my brain. Thanks for clarifying though.